# shell - brace expansion not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Hello, this is a demo of brace expansion\n"

echo "Hello to each one of t{i,a,o}k"
```

output:

```
$ ./hello.sh 
Hello, this is a demo of brace expansion
Hello to each one of t{i,a,o}k
```

why?

using

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quotes suppress brace expansion:

```
$ echo Hello t{i,a,o}k
Hello tik tak tok
$ echo "Hello t{i,a,o}k"
Hello t{i,a,o}k
```

You can quote the rest of your expression. Possibly usefully, if you quote the space before the brace part it stops wordsplitting, so you get something like:

```
$ echo "Hello "t{i,a,o}k
Hello tik Hello tak Hello tok
```